# "bash: command not found" to every command visual studio code debian 11

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I've recently made a fresh installment of debian 11 every command I run in visual studio code using Bash results in "command not found"

```bash
noxar@noxar:~/Documents/tauri beginner classes$ npm 
bash: npm: command not found
```

when I try with the console however

```bash
noxar@noxar:~$ npm

Usage: npm <command>

npm install        install all the dependencies in your project
npm install <foo>  add the <foo> dependency to your project
npm test           run this project's tests
npm run <foo>      run the script named <foo>
npm <command> -h   quick help on <command>
npm -l             display usage info for all commands
npm help <term>    search for help on <term>
npm help npm       more involved overview

All commands:

    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, cache, ci, completion,
    config, dedupe, deprecate, diff, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, exec, explain, explore, find-dupes, fund, get, help,
    hook, init, install, install-ci-test, install-test, link,
    ll, login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    prefix, profile, prune, publish, rebuild, repo, restart,
    root, run-script, search, set, set-script, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, team, test, token, uninstall, unpublish,
    unstar, update, version, view, whoami

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/noxar/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key=value

More configuration info: npm help config
Configuration fields: npm help 7 config

npm@7.5.2 /usr/share/nodejs/npm
```

this is not just limited to npm every command behaves the same

Answer (score 0):

I used flatpak to download visual studio code downloading the .deb instead has fixed the problem